# For loop in Python: continuing iteration outside the for loop

Tags: python, string, loops, for-loop, iteration

I have a function which contains a for-loop. a_laps are the times in seconds needed for a lap which is 400 metres. The function I have so far defined goes like this:

```
LAP_DISTANCE = 400 

def log_track_run(a_laps, a_last_lap_distance):
    r_output = ""
    total_time = 0
    total_distance = 0
    n_laps = len(a_laps)
    i_lap = None
    average_lap_time = None

    for i_lap in range(n_laps):
        lap_time = a_laps[i_lap]
        total_time = total_time + lap_time
        total_distance = total_distance + LAP_DISTANCE
        average_lap_time = (total_time) / (i_lap + 1)
        r_output += f"lap #{i_lap + 1} time = {a_laps[i_lap]}s, average lap time ={round(average_lap_time)}s, {total_distance}m in {total_time}s\n"
```

If a_last_lap_distance = 400 and a_laps = [68, 70, 74, 68], I get the following output which is the correct output:

```
lap #1 time = 68s, average lap time = 68s, 400m in 68s
lap #2 time = 70s, average lap time = 69s, 800m in 138s
lap #3 time = 74sdef log_track_run(a_laps, a_last_lap_distance):
```

In case that a_last_lap_distance is smaller than 400, which means that the last round was not completed, you cannot just add 1 to the i_lap because the lap is not complete. You have to add (a_last_lap_distance)/LAP_DISTANCE to obtain the length of the lap in ratio to 400. I would like to change the iteration computation only for the last item in the range of a_laps - in this example, for the last lap which took 68 seconds.

I have tried with the following function:

```
def log_track_run(a_laps, a_last_lap_distance):
    r_output = ""
    total_time = 0
    total_distance = 0
    n_laps = len(a_laps)
    i_lap = None
    average_lap_time = None

    for i_lap in range(n_laps - 1 ):
        lap_time = a_laps[i_lap]
        total_time = total_time + lap_time
        total_distance = total_distance + LAP_DISTANCE
        average_lap_time = (total_time) / (i_lap + 1)
        r_output += f"lap #{i_lap + 1} time = {a_laps[i_lap]}s, average lap time = {round(average_lap_time)}s, {total_distance}m in {total_time}s\n"
    for i_lap in range(n_laps[-1]):
        lap_time = a_laps[i_lap]
        total_time = total_time + lap_time
        total_distance = total_distance + a_last_lap_distance
        average_lap_time = (total_time) / (i_lap + (a_last_lap_distance)/LAP_DISTANCE)
        r_output += f"lap #{i_lap + 1} time = {a_laps[i_lap]}s, average lap time {round(average_lap_time)}s, {total_distance}m in {total_time}s\n"
```

This yields a syntax error. How can I modify the function so that the second loop is only for the last item in the range while simultaneously based on the previous iteration in the previous for loop?

I tried to write a second for loop that is based on the previous for loop but is only for the lastt item in the lap.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to populate a list `distances` which contains `len(a_laps)-1` ones and `last_distance/LAP_DIST` as the last element. Then, `zip` through both distances and times, and compute the running average:

```
def log_track_run(a_laps, a_last_lap_distance):
    distances = [1] * (len(a_laps) - 1) + [a_last_lap_distance / LAP_DISTANCE]

    total_time = 0
    total_dist = 0

    for n, (dist, time) in enumerate(zip(distances, a_laps), 1):
        total_dist += dist
        total_time += time
        print(f'lap {n}: avg={total_time / total_dist}')
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. How can I incorporate the lap_time into the statement so that the output command is this:

r_output += f"lap #{i_lap + 1} time = {a_laps[i_lap]}s, average lap time = {round(average_lap_time)}s, {total_distance}m in {total_time}s\n"

Comment: For example, I have to print the lap_time in my output, which is indicated in my former function by a_laps[i_lap]

Answer (score 1):

I would start by building a list of times and distances where I would use the parameters `last_lap_distance_actual` and `last_lap_distance_expected` to figure out how to "normalize" the final lap to the expected distance.

I will set a bunch of variables here for completeness, to illustrate how we are working through each lap. There may be some that you don't need.

```py
def log_track_run(laps_times, last_lap_distance_actual=400, last_lap_distance_expected=400):
    total_time_actual = 0.0
    total_time_normalized = 0.0
    total_distance_actual = 0.0
    total_distance_normalized = 0.0
    total_laps_actual = 0.0
    total_laps_normalized = 0.0

    ## ---------------
    ## pre generate a list of times and distances
    ## ---------------
    lap_times_and_distances = [[lap_time, last_lap_distance_expected] for lap_time in laps_times]
    lap_times_and_distances[-1][1] = last_lap_distance_actual
    ## ---------------

    print("--------------------------")
    for lap_time_actual, lap_distance_actual in lap_times_and_distances:
        lap_count_actual = lap_distance_actual / last_lap_distance_expected

        lap_count_normalized = 1
        lap_time_normalized = lap_time_actual * last_lap_distance_expected / lap_distance_actual
        lap_distance_normalized = last_lap_distance_expected

        total_time_actual += lap_time_actual
        total_time_normalized += lap_time_normalized
        total_distance_actual += lap_distance_actual
        total_distance_normalized += lap_distance_normalized
        total_laps_actual += lap_count_actual
        total_laps_normalized += lap_count_normalized

        avg_lap_time_actual = total_time_actual / total_laps_actual
        avg_lap_time_normalized = total_time_normalized / total_laps_normalized

        print(f"Lap: {total_laps_actual:.2f} average lap time = {avg_lap_time_actual:.4f}s {int(total_distance_actual)}m in {total_time_actual:.4f}s")
        if last_lap_distance_expected != lap_distance_actual:
            print(f"\tThis lap was less than {last_lap_distance_expected}m. Projecting results.")
            print(f"\tLap: {total_laps_normalized:.2f} average lap time = {avg_lap_time_normalized:.4f}s {int(total_distance_normalized)}m in {total_time_normalized:.4f}s")
    print("--------------------------")

## a 1500m race outdoors
log_track_run([68, 70, 74, 68], 300)

## a 200m race indoors
log_track_run([26], 200, 200)
```

That should give you:

```
--------------------------
Lap: 1.00 average lap time = 68.0000s 400m in 68.0000s
Lap: 2.00 average lap time = 69.0000s 800m in 138.0000s
Lap: 3.00 average lap time = 70.6667s 1200m in 212.0000s
Lap: 3.75 average lap time = 74.6667s 1500m in 280.0000s
        This lap was less than 400m. Projecting results.
        Lap: 4.00 average lap time = 75.6667s 1600m in 302.6667s
--------------------------

--------------------------
Lap: 1.00 average lap time = 26.0000s 200m in 26.0000s
--------------------------
```

You can probably see how to adjust your print statements if needs be.

Comment: It works now, thank you!